# Are there conditions to whether Yozuru Kagenui walks on the ground or not?

Tags: monogatari-series

During the *Tsukihi Phoenix* Arc of *Nisemonogatari* Yozuru Kagenui is seen not touching the ground. When she first meets Araragi and asks him directions to the cram school, she's standing on benches, and when she goes to leave, she jumps from bench to bench.

When she and Yotsugi Ononoki go to attack Tsukihi at the Araragi's house she is at first standing on the fence. When Tsukihi is seemingly killed by Ononoki she jumps on top of Araragi, pinning him to the ground, but she still stays off of it herself. When she and Ononoki go to leave, she is standing on Ononoki's finger as Ononoki walks away.

But when Araragi and Shinobu fight the two of them in the cram school she is walking on the ground. I am wondering if there is a pattern or condition to when she walks on the ground and when she doesn't?

Comment: IIRC, it is curse, she told about it to Araragi , here the ground may be road or ground that is just above crust, not just the floor

Comment: indeed it was due to a curse that was revealed later in the series. http://bakemonogatari.wikia.com/wiki/Yozuru_Kagenui

Answer (score 4):

Slight spoilers for Tsukimonogatari

It is explained that Kagenui (and another character specific to Tsukimonogatari) had a curse put onto them which prevents them from touching the ground. There's little-to-no mention as to what happens if Kagenui ever does touch the ground, but either way, with the amount of dedication she takes to never stepping on it, it seems to be something relatively serious.

If I remember correctly, this curse was put onto her and the other character for their work on bringing Ononoki into being (as in, in the form she is now).

About her walking on the floor of the cram school ruins, I'd say it's probably because it's the floor of a building, not the actual ground. She's able to walk on structures built on the ground, just not the ground itself.